# time travel kids show

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm looking for a kids show about a blonde girl that travels in time and brings historical figures back to her time to solve there problems
some of the historical figures on the show was Charlie Chaplin, Einstein, Edison, etc.

The time travel machine was in the basement in an old building, I think the show was on abc the show was aired in the 80's or 90's

Comment: I know this isn't the show you're thinking of but it's in the same vein. Voyagers! Unfortunately all the primary actors in this series were male. The main star was John Erik Hexum. He was destined to be a great actor but tragically died from an onset accident involving a prop hand gun.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is "Mentors."  A Canadian show, but matches the premise you have written pretty closely. It ran for four seasons of 13 episodes each. Summary by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentors_%28TV_series%29):

> It was about a boy genius who uses his computer to bring famous historical figures from the past into the present. As an example, he and his girlfriend "summoned" Albert Einstein, Alexander Graham Bell, and Joan of Arc in the first three episodes. Eventually the boy hands the machine over to his two cousins who bring forward figures such as Confucius and Vlad the Impaler.

[IMDB Link for the series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0168350/)